# How does one modify the emo framework to provide your own methods which are to be available in the squirrel language

Tags: objective-c

Can someone clarify what you have to do to create your own methods in emo framework:

for example, I create some objective C code and headers into emo framework, to work with circles.

I place it into the RootViewController.m and it works fine. it generates a circle but not in squirrel language.

How do I make the methods available within the main.nut file as new custom squirrel commands?

```
emo.circleHide();
emo.circleWhatever();
emo.circleSize(2);
```

etc.

Comment: Try to ask on [discussion group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/emo-discuss)

Answer (score 0):

You can add your own functions to tables and classes using the insert operator (<-). Example:

```
emo.foo <- function(){
    print("Yup");
};

emo.foo();
```